# Join problem: throwing error, join extra operand

Tags: text-processing, join

I want to join 3 files on a column which has sorted unique numeric values (those files have only one column of values though) and starts with same prefix for an example "usi".

Now, while I am doing this

```
join -j 1 ../Test_Data/usi* > ../Test_Data/join_output.txt
```

I am finding following error:

> ```
> join: extra operand `usi_rtree_lw_100000.txt'
> Try `join --help' for more information.
> ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`join` accepts only 2 files to join. To operate on 3 file you have to use 2 `join` calls:

```
join -j 1 <(join -j 1 ../Test_Data/usi-1 ../Test_Data/usi-2) ../Test_Data/usi-3 > ../Test_Data/join_output.txt
```

The above command requires `bash`, as uses process substitution. If you use another shell, please specify which.

**Update** according to the comment.
If you know only a file name pattern instead of exact file names, let the shell expand the pattern, capture the expanded list in an array then use the array elements as parameters:

```
file=(../Test_Data/usi*)
join -j 1 <(join -j 1 "${file[0]}" "${file[1]}") "${file[2]}"
```

Comment: actually the problem is , I know only the prefixes of the files,I cant use the exact names of them.

Answer (score 0):

*POSIX* shell variants of [*manatwork*'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52542/165517):

1. `printf '"%s" ' ../Test_Data/usi* | { read a b c ; join $a $b | join - $c ; }`
2. `set -- ../Test_Data/usi* ; join "$1" "$2" | join - "$3"`